# Automation testing for RestApi and UI in one application

Tags: rest, selenium, testing

I have an application in which I need to do UI testing as well as rest Api testing.Could anyone suggest me any testing tool for this.
My framework will be data driven.
Also, it is 20% UI and 80% rest api testing.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It is good that you have decided 80% API tests and 20% UI tests, which will satisfy the test automation pyramid. Well, the test tools and frameworks completely depend on your language of choice.

For API tests

- Java -- RestAssured
- Python -- requests library

For UI tests, Selenium webdriver is my preferred choice.

If you are starting test automation, I would suggest start with reading the documentation.

Comment: yes , I am starting with test automation fresh project. Can I integrate these two into single java project (Selenium and RestAssured))

Comment: They can be a part of same project. The UI tests will follow the API tests and you can have same framework running the entire suite.

Comment: Thanks for your help. One more help needed. My problem statement is to get data from different rest responses and then compare the same. So, using Selenium+ RestAssurred will work?

Comment: @user892077 - Yes you can use Selenium with RestAssured. But just to clarify there is no relation of selenium with restassured, both are independent, its like you are just integrating them to create a common framework which contains both API and UI tests in a single testng.xml file.

Comment: Making an http call, getting response can be done using RestAssured. Selenium doesnot provide any API to perform http specific action. Please go ahead and read the documentation of RestAssured and Selenium; this will clarify a lot of questions.